# R filtering logic

Tags: r, filter, logic, conditional-statements

Need some insight on how to fix this filtering logic.

```
test.session <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
test.start_flag <- c("1","0","0","1","0","0")
test.url <- c("in_list","in_field","out","not_in_list","in_field","out")
test.code_map <- 'tbd'
test.manual_map <- c("1","1","0","0","0","0")
test.df <- data.frame(test.session, test.start_flag, test.url, test.code_map, test.manual_map)
```

I want to generate the `test.code_map` to match the `test.manual_map` vector. I have the first four lines coded, but the logic needs to be tweaked for the 5th and 6th rows. Logic:

- If start flag is 1 and url is 'in_list', then code_map is equal to 1 (done)
- If start flag is 0 and url is 'in_field', then code_map is equal to 1 (done)
- If start flag is 0 and url is 'out' then code_map is equal to 0 (done)
- If start flag is 1 and url is 'not_in_list' then code map is equal to 0 (done)
- If start flag is 0 and url is 'out' then code map is equal to 0 (done - same as above)
- If start flag is 0 and url is 'in_field', then code map is equal to 0 ***need logic tweaked

*** this field needs to be equal to 0 because in this specific session (session B), the starting URL is not equal to the fields I am defining, and therefore all the values for code_map need to be equal to 0 only when this specific condition is met.

Comment: You say in your paragraph "If start flag is 0 and url is 'in_field', then code_map is equal to 1 (done)" and then you say " If start flag is 0 and url is 'in_field', then code map is equal to 0". Which is it you want? Is it dependant on test.session?

Comment: It is dependent on start.flag and url. So if the start flag is equal to 1, and the url is equal to 'not_in_list', then for ALL urls in that session I would need the code to return a 0, even if start flag is 0 and url is 'in_field' because the starting URL was not in the list proposed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of confusing to understand what you want, but it seems like if a test session has a test.url "not_in_list", then all test.code_maps for that test session should be 0. If so, this should work

```
test.df$test.code_map<-ifelse(
  ((test.df$test.start_flag == 1 & test.df$test.url=="in_list")|
  (test.df$test.start_flag == 0 & test.df$test.url=="in_field"& test.df$test.session!="B") &
    !test.session %in% test.df$test.session[test.df$test.url=="not_in_list"]),
  1, 0)
```

Comment: Yes - this does work perfectly if we were to just run the code over this test snippet. I am going to need to run this code over 300k + session ID's so when we write the test.code_map, it has to be dynamic over each session.      But the logic is right though, every time there is a new session name that has a starting url that is not equal to the value 'in_list', then for every single row in that specific session test.code_map must equal 0

Comment: Actually I'm testing this now and it looks good! was taking a different approach to it but this makes it so much cleaner and easier thanks!

Comment: Thanks it did with some minor tweaking! I need to add an end flag to the dataset which I can easily do (1 if the url is the last url in the session, 0 otherwise). How can we adjust this code to make the test.code_map equal to 1 if the end_flag is equal to '1' and the url is 'out'? This would be an addition to the code that is already above.

Comment: That's simple enough to do, just add the logical test (test.df$test.code_map==1 & test.df$test.url=="out") to the above code. You can put it anywhere before that last "&" sign

Comment: Awesome thanks!! *****(test.df$**end_flag**==1 & test.df$test.url=="out")

Comment: Hey so I wrote the function like this: get.test_code <- function(log) {
      log$test.code_map<-ifelse(
            ((log$start_flag == 1 & log$url_flag=="in_list")|
                   (log$start_flag == 0 & log$url_flag=="in_field"& log$sid!="B") |
                   (log$end_flag== 1 & log$url_flag=="out") &
                   !log$sid %in% log$sid[log$url_flag=="not_in_list"]),
            1, 0)     ### but now it isn't giving be the accurate results if the start flag = 1 and start url is not in list, and other URLs that are in field within that session aren't being mapped as 0 anymore?

Comment: I think the positioning of your parentheses were off. Try this: get.test_code <- function(log) { 
  log$test.code_map<-ifelse( 
    ((log$start_flag == 1 & log$url_flag=="in_list")|
       (log$start_flag == 0 & log$url_flag=="in_field") | 
       (log$end_flag== 1 & log$url_flag=="out"))
     & !log$sid %in% log$sid[log$url_flag=="not_in_list"], 1, 0)

Comment: nice sorry am starting to not see straight been staring at a computer for a while!